# Unexpected String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help with this debug issue? Trying to take the variables and throw them in a Change for CSS to get the background to change into a gradient.

```
var gradientAlpha = "#999";
var gradientBravo = "#555";

$('#banner-gradient')
 .change(function() {
    $('.banner-gradient').css({'background': 'linear-gradient(135deg,' + gradientAlpha + ',' + gradientBravo ')'});
})
.change();
```

Comment: there is not enough information to reproduce the issue, you should add more details.  Also, if you want to debug javascript or in this case jquery, you can open the developer tools console in a browser with the page loaded and execute them to see what error does it give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a `+` after `gradientBravo`

`gradientBravo` is a variable which you trying to add to a string. So you should have + before and after.

```
$('#banner-gradient').change(function() {
    $('.banner-gradient').css({'background': 'linear-gradient(135deg,' 
                                         + gradientAlpha + ',' + gradientBravo+')'});
});
```